# GCP Build failed gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

I am deploying my node app on gcp using  `gcloud app deploy`. I have installed gcloud sdk and now when i try to execute deploy command it is resulting in the following error:

```
Step #1: prebuild-install WARN install libusb-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Step #1: make: Entering directory '/app/node_modules/node-hid/build'
Step #1: ../hidapi/linux/hid.c:44:21: fatal error: libudev.h: No such file or directory
Step #1: compilation terminated.
Step #1: hidapi-linux-hidraw.target.mk:101: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/hidapi-linux-hidraw/hidapi/linux/hid.o' failed
Step #1: make: *** [Release/obj.target/hidapi-linux-hidraw/hidapi/linux/hid.o] Error 1
Step #1: make: Leaving directory '/app/node_modules/node-hid/build'
Step #1: gyp ERR! build error 
Step #1: gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
Step #1: gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
Step #1: gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
Step #1: gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
Step #1: gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-1044-gcp
Step #1: gyp ERR! command "/nodejs/bin/node" "/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
Step #1: gyp ERR! cwd /app/node_modules/node-hid
Step #1: gyp ERR! node -v v10.16.1
Step #1: gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
Step #1: gyp ERR! not ok 
Step #1: npm WARN bridge@1.0.0 No description
Step #1: npm WARN bridge@1.0.0 No repository field.
Step #1: 
Step #1: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
Step #1: npm ERR! errno 1
Step #1: npm ERR! node-hid@0.7.9 install: `prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild`
Step #1: npm ERR! Exit status 1
Step #1: npm ERR! 
Step #1: npm ERR! Failed at the node-hid@0.7.9 install script.
```

It started with error of node-hid. I installed it with `npm install --save node-hid`. And then it changed to the error mentioned.

Following is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "bridge",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.16.3"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@binance-chain/javascript-sdk": "^2.14.8",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "bignumber.js": "^5.0.0",
    "bip39": "^3.0.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "generate-password": "^1.4.2",
    "helmet": "^3.21.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.6.11",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.0",
    "node-hid": "^0.7.9",
    "nodemailer": "^6.3.0",
    "prebuild-install": "^5.3.2",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "sha256": "^0.2.0",
    "web3": "^1.2.1"
  }
}
```

And `app.yaml`

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex

# manual_scaling:
#   instances: 1

# resources:
#   cpu: .5
#   memory_gb: 0.5
#   disk_size_gb: 10

# handlers:
#   -url: /
#     static_files: client/build/index.html
#     upload: client/build/index.html
#   -url: /
#     static_dir: client/build
```

Everything work fine on local environment but it produces error while deploying to the cloud.

Comment: According to the first line of the message you are looking for the libsub-1.0 library, this library is not declared in your dependencies nor comes by default in the app engine environment, you can take a look on this document where is explained how to use the package manager:  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/runtime#package_manager

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue (in MAC OS) caused by having locked package file in project folder so conflict was created. Try removing

> `package-lock.json`

from project folder than initiate install again :

```
npm install
```

I hope that helped you too.

Comment: I don't understand negative comment on this because I HAD that issue as mentioned. Please leave comments when commenting negative so people can decide who is wrong.

Comment: Besides, my comment is  to cloud implementation which will be most likely be UNIX/ LINUX server and similar issue can be caused, while WIN can ignore issue due to permission.